# Magic table is immune to CSS, what is this wizardry?

Tags: html, css, html-table, center

I have a super simple HTML table:

```
        <table class="dispdtab">
            <tr>
                <td><b>Dealer: </b></td>
                <td>dealername</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Address: </b></td>
                <td>123 main srr</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Contact: </b></td>
                <td>Bob Dole</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I am just trying to center the stupid table but it ain't havin' it. I keep trying but the table just keeps taunting me, pointing and laughing at my failure.

Here's some CSS I've tried:

```
.dispdtab {
    margin:0 auto;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:.8em;
}
.dispdtab td{
    padding:0 .25em;
}
```

I have tried adding `tbody` after the classname. I have tried adding `display:block;` I'm 'bout to go old school and do one of these bad boys `<center>...</center>`

It may be noteworthy to mention that when I added `border:1px solid black;` only the first row was effected with the border.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [cannot reproduce](http://jsbin.com/uYopiPeD/1/)

Comment: where do you put the css?

Comment: Are there any other styles that are being applied? It sounds like CSS specificity might be at work here.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: It works here. Maybe the path is incorrect ?

Comment: Well of course you can't. Your table is not magic like mine. What outside elements could have this effect. It's in a div which starts out `display:none;` then displayed with javascript.

Comment: css is in an external stylesheet.

Comment: Can you show your full code? Obviously something else is interfering with your table/css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code in action below, you can see that the table is in fact centred, but I had to give the floating `div` a width for this to be realised. If you check out the code and remove the `width` declaration on the `div`, its width defaults to the calculated width of the table and it's no longer apparent the `table` is centred.

In your web designs it is always worth paying attention to giving dimensions to objects. We are told that our designs should be as fluid as possible but there is no shame in specifying widths/heights in pixels at times. The trick is knowing when this is necessary.

http://jsbin.com/oJuxoQU/1/edit

[image]